# Using Harvest Plugin with RAD 8.5 - problems opening perspective com.ca.harvest.ui.harvestPerspective

Tags: ibm-rad, harvest

I have installed the latest version of the Harvest Plug-in for IBM RAD 8.5.

When I try to open the perspective 'ALLFusion Harvest Change Manager' I get the error 'Problems opening perspective 'com.ca.harvest.ui.harvestPerspective'.

or when I click 'Harvest' from the menu and choose 'New Harvest Connection' it says 'The chosen operation is not currently available.'

I have searched but have not been able to find any help. Does anybody have experience with fixing this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing the standalone Harvest Client, configuring it properly and running it prior to opening the perspective 'ALLFusion Harvest Change Manager' in RAD.